# Link to a line in a table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, links

Suppose I have a big table of contents (for example, 20 pages) and I want to make a link to a table of contents of some section in it (for example, it starts on the 11th page and finishes on the 13th page).
So this link should put me at the beginning of this part of the table of contents.

Is it possible? How can I do it?

Comment: Please clarify your objective: Do you wish to be able to (a) jump from a specific line in the table of contents (toc) to a place in a document, or (b) jump from somewhere in the document to a specific line in the toc?

Comment: @Mico (b) option.

Comment: Just for my understanding: what is your use case for scenario b) ?

Comment: Just wondering, why would you want to jump into the TOC instead of the actual content page?

Comment: I want to see a content of that big section, which as I wrote can be several pages

Comment: Functionally speaking, using the navigation window of browsers or pdf readers does the same without having to put more links.

Comment: @MS-SPO Yes, but if you read a big file a lot of times, then scrolling through 12 pages of contents to get to the contents of a desired section is not so comfortable

Comment: Not sure you understood what I described ... Anyway, at least you can make progress now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can patch something into ToC and use `\hypertarget` to create an anchor there. Here is a small example:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[hidelinks,colorlinks,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{One}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Two}
\section{One}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\hypertarget{my_link}{}}
\lipsum[2]

\chapter{Three}
\lipsum[3]

\chapter{Four}
See content of \hyperlink{my_link}{second section}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! But I got error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. ...hapter}{\numberline {3}Three}{4}{chapter.3}

Comment: does replacing `{~}` with an empty bracket `{}` resolve this?

Comment: Thank you, works well!

Comment: Thanks for confirming this. I should rectify my solution as well.